# Simple UITextView crashing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextview, exc-bad-access

I'm trying to use a simple `UITextView` in a basic view, but it causes the app to crash sporadically. Sometimes it crashes while I'm typing something in it, sometimes when I'm scrolling, sometimes after I hit the return key. From the stack trace, it looks like it's being caused by graphics or animation related code for rendering UI elements for spell checking, grammar checking, etc.

Why is this crashing my app? Do I need to import additional libraries, or do I need to specify some kind of delegate for the UITextView? I literally just have a simple UITextView in a barebones view, nothing fancy.

Here's the stack trace:

```
Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.
(gdb) bt
#0  0x9535f9b1 in ?? ()
#1  0x9534c33f in ?? ()
#2  0x9534c13e in ?? ()
#3  0x9634df5c in ?? ()
#4  0x9418d244 in CGDataProviderRetain ()
#5  0x963b7036 in ?? ()
#6  0x98263486 in CGImageReadCreateWithProvider ()
#7  0x982633a2 in CGImageSourceCreateWithDataProvider ()
#8  0x020c0947 in CGImageCreateWithPNGDataProvider ()
#9  0x02ebfeed in WKGraphicsCreateImageFromBundleWithName ()
#10 0x02ebfc3b in WebCore::GraphicsContext::drawLineForMisspellingOrBadGrammar ()
#11 0x02ebf9cb in WebCore::InlineTextBox::paintSpellingOrGrammarMarker ()
#12 0x02e73932 in WebCore::InlineTextBox::paintDocumentMarkers ()
#13 0x02e730a1 in WebCore::InlineTextBox::paint ()
#14 0x02e717ef in WebCore::InlineFlowBox::paint ()
#15 0x02e71565 in WebCore::RootInlineBox::paint ()
#16 0x02e71220 in WebCore::RenderLineBoxList::paint ()
#17 0x0354c451 in WebCore::RenderBlock::paintContents ()
#18 0x02e6d7bd in WebCore::RenderBlock::paintObject ()
#19 0x02e6ed51 in WebCore::RenderBlock::paint ()
#20 0x02e6dcf2 in WebCore::RenderBlock::paintChildren ()
#21 0x02e6d7bd in WebCore::RenderBlock::paintObject ()
#22 0x02e6ed51 in WebCore::RenderBlock::paint ()
#23 0x02e6c502 in WebCore::RenderLayer::paintLayer ()
#24 0x02e6bce3 in WebCore::RenderLayer::paintLayer ()
#25 0x02e6b635 in WebCore::RenderLayer::paint ()
#26 0x02e6b3de in WebCore::FrameView::paintContents ()
#27 0x03bd71da in -[WebFrame(WebInternal) _drawRect:contentsOnly:] ()
#28 0x03bd7104 in -[WebHTMLView drawSingleRect:] ()
#29 0x02e6af68 in _WKViewDraw ()
#30 0x02e6b03f in _WKViewDraw ()
#31 0x02e6b03f in _WKViewDraw ()
#32 0x02e6b03f in _WKViewDraw ()
#33 0x02e6b03f in _WKViewDraw ()
#34 0x02e6adb0 in WKViewDisplayRect ()
#35 0x02e6ad41 in WKWindowDrawRect ()
#36 0x02e6a9d3 in WebCore::TileCache::drawLayer ()
#37 0x04041d63 in backing_callback ()
#38 0x0404161e in CABackingStoreUpdate ()
#39 0x040407f4 in -[CALayer _display] ()
#40 0x02e6a3d4 in -[TileLayer display] ()
#41 0x040402b1 in CALayerDisplayIfNeeded ()
#42 0x0403f65b in CA::Context::commit_transaction ()
#43 0x0403f2b0 in CA::Transaction::commit ()
#44 0x04046f5b in CA::Transaction::observer_callback ()
#45 0x02391d1b in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ ()
#46 0x02326987 in __CFRunLoopDoObservers ()
#47 0x022efc17 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#48 0x022ef280 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#49 0x022ef1a1 in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#50 0x02c152c8 in GSEventRunModal ()
#51 0x02c1538d in GSEventRun ()
#52 0x002e2b58 in UIApplicationMain ()
```

**EDIT**: it seems like this is indeed being caused by the autocorrection functionality, as the stack trace alludes to. If I set the "Correction" property under "Text Input Traits" in Interface Builder (I believe it's the autocorrectionType property of the UITextInputTraits protocol) to "No", then the problem goes away. With autocorrection on, I can always reproduce the bug by typing words that are misspelled.

Another thing to note is that this is with the latest iOS 4.1 SDK that I just downloaded yesterday, so I don't know if this is a UITextView bug in the latest SDK or what.

**EDIT 2**: Wow, I'm really stumped by this. I created a few new projects from scratch and tried to display modal view controllers with UITextViews, and they all worked with no problem. However, when I try to do the same in my actual app - no matter which controller I try to invoke a modal view controller from - it always crashes. I've boiled the code down to the barebones, and it still crashes. Here's how I initialize a modal view controller:

```
- (IBAction)showFeedback:(id)sender {
    FooViewController *controller = [[FooViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FooView" bundle:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
    [controller release];
}
```

FooViewController is just a skeleton view controller generated by Xcode that inherits from UIViewController. Nothing is overridden. My nib file just contains an empty view with a single vanilla UITextView. Everything else is the default.

The crash always happens immediately after I type in a misspelled word, and the simulator tries to display red underlines.

I've tried running with NSZombieEnabled as well, and I don't see anything in the logs about messages being sent to zombies.

My app is pretty simple - a tab based app with navigation controllers for each of my 5 tabs. My 5 custom view controllers are then set as the root controllers of each of the navigation controllers. I currently have one of my custom view controllers create and present the modal controller. I've tried commenting out any release calls in the parent view controller, to no avail.

What I don't understand is, what objects are the graphics routines trying to access that may have been released (or not retained) that fall under my application's responsibility with respect to memory management? The only thing possible, in my mind, is the UITextView, and I've tried declaring it as a property with retain, and setting it as an outlet with Interface Builder. Still, the same crash.

Any help is greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: Need more details: (1) How are you adding the text view to the "basic view"? Do you use Interface builder or do you add it programmatically? (2) If programmatically then post the creation/addition code.

Comment: I'm using Interface Builder, and the UITextView is connected to an outlet declared in the view controller. That's pretty much it. One thing I didn't mention is that the view controller is presented as a modal view controller. I just follow Apple's sample code in the docs for "Modal View Controllers" to initialize the view controller from a nib, and present it modally. The modal view contains the UITextView, which just crashes for unknown reasons.

Comment: Turns out that there's one particular image that's causing the crash. When this particular image is loaded with [UIImage imageWithData:...], subsequent interactions with the UITextView that result in spelling underlines leads to a crash. This only happens with one image, which doesn't seem to be malformed or anything. I've filed this as a bug with Apple.

Answer (score 2):

EXC_BAD_ACCESS basically means your accessing memory that is not in use by your App. My guess is you are editing a a variable or accessing a variable that you have already released. Comment out your releases and see how that goes.

EDIT: Could also mean you are not retaining a variable that needs to be.

Comment: I'm only calling release when the view controller is dealloc'ed (and I guess implicitly when its view is unloaded), but that doesn't happen when the app crashes. If you look at the stack trace, it's clearly being caused by graphics/animation related code.

Comment: You could also not be retaining it properly. Its hard to tell with no code. I wouldn't look at the stack trace because for example if its been autoreleased it could crash at a random point or a point that its requiring access to a no longer retained object way in the guts of the UITextField. You could also for example not be retaining the modal view properly and when you click the text field and it updates goes to update the view and its not retained it would crash like yours has. Hard to say but I would be very surprised that its not caused by either releasing too early or not retaining an ob

Comment: Do the UITextField or the UIView object of the modal view controller have to be manually retained? The UIView object is always retained, since it's referenced by the UIViewController (or child classes thereof) instance. I've created some sample apps and didn't connect the UITextField to an outlet, and it still worked fine. I've been going on a debugging hunt with memory management in mind (since a few people have mentioned it), but I still can't figure out the problem. See my original post for updated code.

Comment: Shouldn't but you have something strange going on. Retain all your objects and then work backwards.

Comment: It turns out that it's being caused by a particular image. After that particular image is loaded by [UIImage imageWithData:], the UITextView will crash when interacted with with autocorrection turned on. I was able to reproduce this by creating a new app from scratch. I've filed this as a bug with Apple, as even a malformed image shouldn't cause other UI elements to crash.

Comment: It would be interesting to see the particular bare bones app uploaded somewhere as its surprising its a bug. If it ends up being a bug though make sure you place it as an answer and tick it correct

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced this same bug. I'm using text views in a table view, and it doesn't happen when autocorrection is set to off.

Comment: Does this only happen when you load an image with UIImage? I can only reproduce this bug when a load a *particular* image using UIImage. Only this particular image causes the text view to crash.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I have some images elsewhere on the page, are you saying those are interfering with the textview somehow?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem - I had stupidly set my TextView instead of the text color!  So, I had this:

```
self.myTextView = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
```

instead of this:

```
self.myTextView.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
```